# avoid gradient breaking with `torch.where` for combining tensors

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

Here is a a very brief example of the problem I am having and what I am after

```
nan = float("nan")
t = th.Tensor([[nan, nan], [0, 0], [.1, .1],])

l = nn.Linear(2, 2)
tf = l(t)

tf = th.where(t != t, th.zeros_like(t), tf)
(10 - tf.sum()).backward()
print(l.weight.grad)
```

why is the gradient nan (especially when the following is just fine)

```
nan = float("nan")
t = th.Tensor([[nan, nan], [0, 0], [.1, .1],])
t_o = th.where(t != t, th.zeros_like(t), t)

l = nn.Linear(2, 2)
tf = l(t_o)

(10 - tf.sum()).backward()
print(l.weight.grad)
```

giving the correct gradient:

```
tensor([[-0.1000, -0.1000],
        [-0.1000, -0.1000]])
```

---

#### The Full Question

Suppose I have `t` tensors of shape `(n, f_i)` where `f_i` can be different for each `t`. Furthermore, each of these `t` tensors may have some `nan` rows (assume each tensor represents a type of object and I want a shared embedding of all those objects). What I would like to do is "assimilate" these tensors into a shared space.

Here is a minimal module attempting to do this:

```
import torch as th
import torch.nn as n

class Assimilation(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, assimilation_dim: int, *type_in_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self._assimilation_dim = assimilation_dim
        self._type_in_dim = type_in_dim
        self._mixins = nn.ModuleList(
            [
                nn.Linear(in_dim, self._assimilation_dim, bias=False)
                for in_dim in self._type_in_dim
            ]
        )

    def forward(self, *x: th.Tensor):
        assims, = []
        for to_assim, assim_layer in zip(x, self._mixins):
            assimilated = assim_layer(to_assim)
            assims.append(assimilated)

        # the problem area (I believe)
        current = assims[0]
        for i in range(1, len(assims)):
            current = th.where(current != current, assims[i], current)
        return current
```

Note, the implementation has some more requirements like allowing tensors of more arbitrary shapes `(*, n, f_i)` for more leading dimensions. For this reason, I wanted to avoid tracking indices as things get more complex when batching this kind of data (or adding time, etc) - especially since torch has [bad fancy indexing](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1080).

However, when trying to use it you can observe that the gradient breaks from the `th.where`

```
ass = Assimilation(2, 2, 3) # :)
nan = float("nan")

t1 = th.Tensor([[nan, nan], [0, 0], [.1, .1],])
t2 = th.Tensor([[100, 100, 100], [nan, nan, nan], [nan, nan, nan],])

res = ass(t1, t2)
print(t1.shape, t2.shape)
print(res.shape)
print(res)
(10 - res.sum()).backward()
print(ass._mixins[0].weight.grad) # all nan 
print(ass._mixins[1].weight.grad) # all nan
```

Is there a reason `th.where` should be breaking the gradient here? How can I avoid this?